# How to execute batch file from codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter

I want to execute a batch file in path/URL when calling my function from the controller. How does it?

```
class myController extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function myCall() {
        system("cmd /c C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\batchfile\myfile.bat");
    }
}
```

no response

Answer (score 0):

see this link: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Make sure you are sending the right arguments for your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

call echo on your call to the `system()` function to get the output (Last line of the output).

```
function myCall() {
  echo system("cmd /c C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\batchfile\myfile.bat");
}
```